# aspnetcore: how to programatically call another controller based on a URI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

Alternative title this question could have had:

### What is the Asp.NET core equivalent of HttpControllerSelector?

---

I have an asp.net core 2.0 website, and I want to delegate/proxy http requests, something like this:

1. Client makes "wrapped" request e.g. `GET server/api/batch?url1=api/thing1&url2=api/thing2`
2. Server unwraps the wrapped request - in this example, we now have two urls for `api/thing1` and `api/thing2`
3. Server internally calls the underlying URL's - in this example simulate a GET `api/thing` and GET `api/thing2`

In old asp.net WebApi the key to this was to new up an internal HttpRequest, and then call  `Configuration.Services.GetHttpControllerSelector().SelectController(request)` to get whichever controller was configured against that URL.

In Asp.Net core, I can't find how to do it? I realise if I know the controller up front I can just create an instance of it, but I can't seem to get across the URL -> Routing -> Controller Type gap

Comment: so, what did you do?

Comment: @cosh I just added an answer explaining what I did. It's kind of yuck but hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

So, at the time of asking this question, I dug around through the ASPNetCore 2 source code, compiled it myself and tried to figure out a way to achieve it.

I arrived at the conclusion that this wasn't possible without changes to the framework. I can't remember the exact reasons as it was a few months ago now, but basically we need to gain access to the main `IRouteCollection` in order to map a route string to a controller/action, however the IRouteCollection is only in the Routing Middleware. Because Middlewares in ASPNetCore are simply a chain of lambda functions, there's no way for one middleware to interrogate other middlewares, or even get a collection of them. All you get is a list of Lambda's with no way to dig through to the Routing data on the other side.

So, given that I couldn't determine a way to build a generalised solution, for the original question ("batching" multiple requests) I built a specific solution for the specific problem I had. In my instance, I batch requests together, but I only batch a specific subset of requests (to about 6 controller/action methods).

There's a whole ton of helper code associated with it, but the general idea is this excerpt:

```
if(httpContext.Request.Path.TryMatchRoute("api/{itemType}/{id}/updates/{bookmark?}", out routeValues) &&
    routeValues.TryGetString("itemType", out string itemType) &&
    routeValues.TryGetInt("id", out int id)) 
    {
        routeValues.TryGetString("bookmark", out string bookmark);
        queryParams.TryGetString("fields", out var fields);

        switch (itemType) {
        case "animals":
            return InvokeController<AnimalsController>(async controller =>
                await controller.GetUpdates(id, bookmark, fields).ConfigureAwait(false));
        case "vegetables":
            return InvokeController<VegetablesController>(async controller =>
               await controller.GetUpdates(id, bookmark, fields).ConfigureAwait(false));
        ...
```

Note: `TryMatchRoute` is a helper function I have which uses a `TemplateSelector` to pattern match on a route string. `InvokeController` is also a function I have which encapsulates the boilerplate of instantiating the controller and setting up an `HttpContext` using `IHttpContextFactory` and all that guff needed to invoke the controller correctly.

I wanted to do it this way because I have specific knowledge of all the `GetUpdates` methods that are being batched together and I want to merge their results in a particular way.

---

I did have one other instance where rather than "batching" requests together I needed to "tunnel" them and I didn't need specific knowledge of the result objects (although it would have been convenent). I achieved this by effectively standing up an entire internal copy of the ASPNetCore server stack but replacing Kestrel with a fake layer. It's kind of disgusting but also kind of neat. As above, this is not complete code but you can get the idea:

```
void Main() 
{
    m_server = new FakeServer();

    var builder = Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .UseStartup<InternalServerStartup>()
        .UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.SuppressStatusMessagesKey, "True")
        .ConfigureServices(services => {
            services.AddSingleton<IServer>(m_server); // this causes the WebHostBuilder to fire requests at our fake server
        });

    var host = builder.Build();
    host.Start();
}

// This class solely exists for us capture the instance of HostingApplication that MVC creates internally so we can invoke it directly
protected class FakeServer : IServer
{
    public HostingApplication HostingApplication { get; private set; } = null;

    public IFeatureCollection Features => new FeatureCollection();

    public void Dispose()
    { }

    public Task StartAsync<TContext>(IHttpApplication<TContext> application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if(application is HostingApplication standardContextApp) {
            HostingApplication = standardContextApp;
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

TunneledResponse OnTunneledRequest(string url, string method, string[] headers, byte[] body)
{
    var host = m_server.HostingApplication;

    var responseBodyStream = new MemoryStream();

    var features = new FeatureCollection();
    features.Set<IHttpRequestFeature>(new HttpRequestFeature());
    features.Set<IHttpResponseFeature>(new HttpResponseFeature { Body = responseBodyStream });

    var ctx = host.CreateContext(features);

    var httpContext = ctx.HttpContext;

    var targetUri = new Uri(url);

    httpContext.Request.Scheme = "fakescheme";
    httpContext.Request.Host = new HostString("fakehost"); // if host is missing, things crash down the line: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2718
    httpContext.Request.Path = targetUri.AbsolutePath;
    httpContext.Request.Method = method;
    httpContext.Request.QueryString = new QueryString(targetUri.Query);

    for (var i = 0; i < headers.Length / 2; i++)
        httpContext.Request.Headers.Add(headers[i * 2], headers[i * 2 + 1]);


    try { 
        await host.ProcessRequestAsync(ctx);

        responseBodyStream.Position = 0; // aspnet will have written to it, seek back to the start

        return new TunneledResponse {
            statusCode = httpContext.Response.StatusCode,
            headers = httpContext.Response.Headers.SelectMany(h => new[] { h.Key, h.Value.FirstOrDefault() }).ToArray(),
            body = responseBodyStream.ToArray()
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: any update in the newer version of ASP.NET Core 5?